# Exclude blank results when running Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a Powershell script that creates a phone directory from the information stored in Active Directory.

I have created the following script, and it runs as expected; but it also includes the names of staff who do not have an associated phone number.

Is there a way to add a filter to the script to exclude user details if they do not have a phone number?

```
import-module activedirectory

$d = Get-Date 
    "Date: " +$d.ToShortDateString()
    "Time: " +$d.ToShortTimeString()

$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:blue;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:PaleGoldenrod}"
$a = $a + "</style>"
$Pre = "<h2>Phone Directory</h2>"
$Post = "<br><br>Time / Date Generated $d"


Get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Test, DC=Domain, DC=net' -Properties sn, GivenName, OfficePhone, Department | Select-Object sn, GivenName, OfficePhone, Department | Sort-Object sn | ConvertTo-Html -head $a -PreContent $Pre -PostContent $Post | Out-File c:\temp\dir.html

Invoke-Expression C:\Temp\dir.html
```

Many thanks,

Peter D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use early filtering whenever possible, and do yourself a favor and fold your code at the pipes to make it easier to read and maintain:

```
Get-ADUser -filter "OfficePhone -like '*'" -SearchBase 'OU=Test, DC=Domain, DC=net' -Properties sn, GivenName, OfficePhone, Department |
 Select-Object sn, GivenName, OfficePhone, Department |
 Sort-Object sn |
 ConvertTo-Html -head $a -PreContent $Pre -PostContent $Post |
 Out-File c:\temp\dir.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Less pipelining should help. Get a list of all the users and filter it later.

```
# Save all the users into an array:
$users = Get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Test, DC=Domain, DC=net' -Properties sn, GivenName, OfficePhone, Department | Select-Object sn, GivenName, OfficePhone, Department
# Look for users that have at least one digit in their officephone. Adjust as needed
$usersWithPhones = $users | ? { $_.OfficePhone -match "\d+"}
# Pass the filtered results along the pipeline
$usersWithPhones | Sort-Object sn | ConvertTo-Html -head $a -PreContent $Pre -PostContent $Post | Out-File c:\temp\dir.html
```

You can add the filtering statement into the pipeline. I wouldn't. Maintenance for a script that tries to do lots of things with oneliners is a headache. Performance is not really an issue with scripting anyway, so you should strive for easy to read, easy to maintenance solutions.

Comment: "Performance is not really an issue with scripting anyway" Depends. I've run out of memory when pulling in large directories without proper filtering. We don't know the size of this particular one, so we should assume worst-case.

Comment: @Trondh I agree. Have you got an idea how to filter the non-phonenumbered ones on LDAP query level? That would improve the solution even more.

Comment: According to the doc, you can specify Get-ADUser -Filter {<property> -like "*"} like @mjolinor is doing in the other reply. Should work.